# how do I reassemble TCP packet in LUA dissector?

Tags: tcp, lua, wireshark-dissector

I have a dissector that runs above the TCP protocol and has data that flows on more than one TCP packet.

I want to assemble the data before I convert everything, so I understood that I need `tcp_dissect_pdus()` for it, but I can't find documentation or examples for it.

Can anyone direct me to it or help me understand how I use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no wslua API for tcp_dissect_pdus. But you can implement it yourself.

If you want to assemble pdu that span two or more packets it's rather simple:

```
function slicer.dissector(tvb, pinfo, tree)
    ...
    local pdu_length = get_pdu_length(...)
    if pdu_length > tvb:len() then
        pinfo.desegment_len = pdu_length - tvb:len()
    else
        do_dissection(tvb, pifo, tree)
    end
    return
end
```

If you don't know exact length of the pdu you can do:

```
        pinfo.desegment_len = DESEGMENT_ONE_MORE_SEGMENT
```

You should read [README.developer](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=doc/README.developer) section 2.7.

Comment: according to the documentation my dissector will be called only after the buffer contains the amount of bytes that I put in _pinfo.desegment_len_, but if f.e. I have a message size 3890 bytes, the dissector is called in every packet, not only when it gets the amount of bytes. do you know why can it be?

Comment: Starting in Wireshark 1.99.2, there is a Lua binding for tcp_dissect_pdus. https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Proto.html#lua_fn_dissect_tcp_pdus_tvb__tree__size__func__func___desegment__

Comment: For those wondering, 1.99.2 is a [development release](https://www.wireshark.org/news/). Not sure exactly when this feature landed in a stable release.